# How to get DVD Player (Mac OS X) to stop being the frontmost window

Tags: macos, mac

So DVD Player likes to be the topmost window on Mac OS X, and if you try to push it off the side of the screen in creeps back on. I don't like this and I'd like to disable that feature. Is there a way to disable it?

Mostly it's just annoying, but recently the program hung, and when I went to use "Force Quit..." the force quit window opened in the same area of the screen as the DVD Player window, which was sitting in front of the screen blocking me from doing the Force Quit. I had to open up a terminal window and resort to "ps ax" + manual search for process # + "kill". Scary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure "View->Viewer Above Other Apps" is not selected.